# Sort on substring of line (not using a delimiter)

Tags: text-processing, solaris, sort, data

I need some help understanding how the sort command is working in the following examples:

### cat testfile

The input data:

```
thisfilehasduplicates
thissnowhasfallen
thisduckhasdied
thishallwasfull
berthammwasaclown
fredsimmisprimeminister
fredalbaisabinman
janetyceisscottish
janeouseisenglish
janellyriswelsh
```

The aim here is to sort and deduplicate by the first four characters. I have read that `-k1.1,1.4` will achieve this by sorting by the first four characters of the first field. The comma denotes a range of characters with `1.4` meaning, field 1, character 4.

### sort -u -t -k1.1,1.4 testfile

I interpret this version as `-t` followed by blank to mean that there is no field separator, however I suppose it could mean field separator is whitespace, however it somehow interferes with the `-k` and `-u` flags and doesn't give me what I want:

```
berthammwasaclown
fredalbaisabinman
fredsimmisprimeminister
janellyriswelsh
janeouseisenglish
janetyceisscottish
thisduckhasdied
thisfilehasduplicates
thishallwasfull
thissnowhasfallen
```

### sort -u -k1.1,1.4 testfile

This version, without the `-t` flag does give exactly what is required, deduplication on the first four characters, at least I think that's what it is doing

```
berthammwasaclown
fredalbaisabinman
janellyriswelsh
thisduckhasdied
```

I've read the man pages on my distribution (SunOS 5.10), but I don't fully understand the sections relating to the `-k` and `-t` flags, especially when using the dot notation in a key specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sort -u -t -k1.1,1.4 testfile
>   I interpret this version as -t followed by blank to mean that there is no field separator, however I suppose it could mean field separator is whitespace,

Neither of those. The tokenization of arguments passed to a program on Unix is defined by the shell, not the program; and in most Unix programs since forever, if (a leading argument which is) an option/flag requires a value and you don't supply it as part of the same argument, the next argument is used as the value. `-t -k1.1,1.4` uses `-k1.1,1.4` as the field separator, truncating it to one character namely `-`. As a result there is no `-k` option recognized, so it sorts using the default key definition, which is the whole line.

*GNU* sort in this case gives an error, saying that 'tab' value (i.e. the value of `-t`) is multi-character; this behavior is more helpful, but not required by either tradition or standard. On SunOS-aka-Solaris, utilities are not required to and many actually do not conform to XPG-and-POSIX unless you specify the xpg4 or xpg6 version -- did you? -- but on my (now virtualized) Solaris 10 test system, both `/usr/bin/sort` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/sort` have this less-helpful behavior.

If you did want the space *character* as the field separator -- which would be meaningless for your data, which contains no space characters -- you need to tell the *shell* to pass a space character either as part of the `-t` argument or as an additional argument:

```
sort -t" " -k1.1,1.4
sort -t' ' -k1.1,1.4
sort -t\  -k1.1,1.4
sort "-t " -k1.1,1.4
sort '-t ' -k1.1,1.4

sort -t " " -k1.1,1.4
sort -t ' ' -k1.1,1.4
sort -t \  -k1.1,1.4
```

Note that in Unix-type systems (whether or not Unix-trademark branded, which SunOS originally wasn't) 'whitespace' usually does not mean only the space character; it usually includes at least the space *and (horizontal) tab* characters, and often 'vertical' space like LF, VT, FF as well. Standard `sort` can use only a single character as the field separator, so that cannot be whitespace. In contrast shell, and awk (by default), do parse fields using multiple whitespace characters.